# AngularJS - Different HTML according to index in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What is the best way to change the HTML inside an ng-repeat, according to it's current index? I want to output two divs that fill the container vertically, and the third div will fill half, on top of the fourth div which fills another half. Repeat for the next elements. Example in the following image:

[image]

I thought of incrementing my `$index` in the `ng-repeat` by doing `{{$index = $index + 1}}`, evaluating the `$index` inside an ng-if to see if it is the desired value. But I am unable to increment the index that way (when I print it, it shows as 33, 34, 35... etc). Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

As it stands, I forgot to add a small detail. The number 3 and 4, or 7 and 8 need to be printed in the same ng-repeat. This is a carousel (slick-js) and those half-divs need to be in the same "slide" in the carousel. The only way is printing them at the same time, that is, both `$index` and `$index+1`, otherwise they are treated as different slideshows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IraQ2eWKwkhMed3KenbI?p=preview)

You can use this syntax :

```
<div ng-repeat="div in divs" ng-class="{'up' : $index % 4 === 3, 'down': $index % 4 === 2}">{{div}} = {{$index}}</div>
```

Grouping by 4 elements ng-class will add the class 'up' on each 3rd and 'down' on each 4th

EDIT :

What about using a new array with all your slide like this :

```
 //you'll need to build it
 $scope.slideArray = [1,2,[3,4],5,6,7];
```

and displaying it like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in slideArray">
    <div ng-repeat="subSlide in slide">
       {{subSlide}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Using some good CSS and adpating this to your need should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question because I forgot a small detail. The half-divs need to be printed in the same ng-repeat, that is, I need to access both the current $index and $index+1 in the same iteration of ng-repeat.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in a while :)

Answer (score 2):

May be you can maintain an array of numbers based on your requirement of how many divs you want to render. Inside `ng-repeat` using the `$index` get the value of array item and render the `divs` accordingly.

E.g:

```
$scope.items = [];
$scope.divsToRender = [1,1,2,1,1,2];

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
 //Here use divsToRender[$index] and get the number of divs to render based on current index
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question because I forgot a small detail. The half-divs need to be printed in the same ng-repeat, that is, I need to access both the current $index and $index+1 in the same iteration of ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2):

`$index` will give you a the index of the current item in `ng-repeat`. You can use that in your `ng-if`. It is zero based. In your example your ng-if could be something like this:

```
<ng-if="$index == 2 || $index == 3 || $index == 6 || $index == 7">
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question because I forgot a small detail. The half-divs need to be printed in the same ng-repeat, that is, I need to access both the current $index and $index+1 in the same iteration of ng-repeat.